# How can I delay return of CallNextHookEx or PostMessage to simulate delayed mouse events?

Tags: java, winapi, callback, mouseevent, jna

My mouse does occasional double clicks and now I'm trying to build a tool that detects invalid mouseup/mousdowns and blocks them from being propagated.

The double-clicks are actually triggered by the mouse losing contact and then receiving it again (similar to a short-circuit but without electricity). It becomes very clearly visible if I try to drag (e.g. by selecting text): the mouse loses the drag multiple times. Now I'm trying to ignore such intermediate mouse-up events and the following mouse-down event if it happens in short succession to prevent this from happening.

I managed to hook and block events using JNA. However, my problem is a bit more complex: I only know that I should block a mouseup event if the mousedown event happens less than  ms later, so in fact I first have to block the mouseup event, wait  ms, then either trigger the mouseup event (if no mousedown was detected during that time) or do nothing (if there was a mousedown event within the tolerance time which btw should also be blocked). However, I only managed to find out how to broadcast a mouseup event (this always triggers a click on the windows button, so I guess it doesn't include the location), but not how I could properly trigger the actual mouseup event that I blocked in the first place.

Here's my implementation which does proper blocking but triggers the click wrongly afterwards (note that this is not the  implementation but just a simplified version to test the simulated event).

```
public class LowLevelMouseProcImpl implements LowLevelMouseProc {
    private User32 userInstance;
    private HHOOK hhk;
    private final HWND HWND_BROADCAST = new HWND(Pointer.createConstant(0xFFFF));
    public LowLevelMouseProcImpl(User32 userInstance, AtomicBoolean threadFinish) {
        this.userInstance = userInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHook(HHOOK hook) {
        hhk = hook;
    }

    @Override
    public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if (nCode < 0) {
            return userInstance.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
        switch (wParam.intValue()) {
            case MouseHook.WM_LBUTTONUP:
                new Thread(() -> {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    userInstance.PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, MouseHook.WM_LBUTTONUP, wParam, lParam);
                    //userInstance.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
                }).start();
                return new LRESULT(1);
                // break;
            case MouseHook.WM_RBUTTONUP:
                break;
            case MouseHook.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    userInstance.PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, MouseHook.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, wParam, lParam);
                }).start();
                return new LRESULT(1);
                // break;
            case MouseHook.WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return userInstance.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I could post the message properly?

Comment: How is an invalid double-click defined? If it is a normal double-click, how should you distinguish?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem. Because I have encountered the problem of automatically turning into double-click after clicking, in the end I found that "Turn on ClickLock" should be unselected. See this [screensnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQI7V.png).

Comment: ClickLock has nothing to do with my problem, as I said it's a hardware problem. I described how the invalid double-click is detected in the second paragraph. Maybe I described it a little incorrect though. I will update the description.

Comment: This time is difficult to control. Because when the left mouse button is pressed, there will be multiple events of mouse loss. This makes it difficult to get the double-click time. In other words, as long as your left mouse button is pressed, the event of losing the mouse will continue to occur. My suggestion is to seek the average time of mouse loss and prevent the  mousedown event and mouseup event within the average time. Of course, this method is very rough, but in addition to this method, I can't think of other methods that can get your actual mouse release event.

Comment: yes, that's what was my intention in the first place. my question is not about how it can be done in theory, but how it can be done practically. in order to block one event and fire it later (or not), i need a way to fire it properly. this is what my whole question is about.

Answer (score 0):

**in order to block one event and fire it later (or not), i need a way to fire it properly. this is what my whole question is about.**

You can use the `WH_MOUSE_LL` to hook the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` events. When you press the left mouse button for the first time, a timer is set to prevent `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` events within a specific time. After a certain time, a left mouse button release event is automatically sent.

This is a c++ code sample, I am not familiar with JNA, but you can use it as a reference.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define time_ 2000    //average time

HHOOK mouseHook;
BOOL Fisrt_LBDOWN = TRUE;
BOOL LBUP = FALSE;
int ID = 0;

void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{   
    //After time_, automatically trigger WM_LBUTTONUP
    LBUP = TRUE;
    INPUT Input = { 0 };
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));   //Simulate left mouse button release
}

LRESULT __stdcall MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
             // The first time the left mouse button is pressed
             if (Fisrt_LBDOWN) 
             {
                //Trigger the timer to prevent WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP within the time_.
                ID = SetTimer(NULL, 0, time_, (TIMERPROC)&f); 
                Fisrt_LBDOWN = FALSE;
                return 0;
             }
             return 1;           
        }
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            if (LBUP)
            {
                //Kill the timer and initialize all variables
                KillTimer(NULL, ID);
                Fisrt_LBDOWN = TRUE;
                LBUP = FALSE;
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Failed to install mousehook!" << endl;
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHook);
}

int main()
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    ReleaseHook();
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with c++, so these questions might sound stupid :D where does `f` get its parameters from? And where does `SendInput` come from? Is it part of `Windows.h`? Also, if I understood it properly, it doesn't really do what I intend to do, it simply blocks all mouse up events until the timer fires and then simulates one, right? Anyways, the implementation details are not my problem, I only have a problem with simulating an event properly.

Comment: @GernotRaudner As I said before, you can't control mouse-up events, so you can only try to prevent all mouse-up and down events in an average time. For example, when you press the left mouse button and drag, the mouse will automatically send an mouse-up event, which you cannot predict.

Comment: @GernotRaudner [TimerProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer#remarks).  [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) is part of `Windows.h`.